# Creating message in 'Messaging'

Tags: windows-phone, messaging

I want a message from my application to show up in the Windows Phone 'Messaging Hub' without having to send it as a text message. Is it possible to do this?

The application doesn't have to be distributed via the Marketplace, so any private apis would also do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It isn't possible, during WP 7.X or WP8 SDK. 
 I solved similar problem by creating `HTTP Post Request` with `json`(device info, message and other) as parameter. Then posted to my own server, which performed the work instead of the phone.
 Hope it's help you.

Answer (score 2):

At this time it isn't possible, as there's no API for that. You can pre-fill a SMS using the `SmsComposeTask`, but that's the only interaction you get with that hub.

Comment: Oke, any 'other' method to do this? Using private apis or something like that? My app doesn't have to be distributed through the store so I don't have to worry about MS verification.